# Clustering on single machine fails with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, cluster-computing, stomp

I'm using RabbitMQ. I'm trying to do clustering on Window 7 machines. I followed procedure on below link.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine

I have used following commands.

```
SET RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673 
SET RABBITMQ_SERVER_START_ARGS="-rabbitmq_management listener [{port,15673}]" 
SET RABBITMQ_NODENAME=hare 
rabbitmq-server -detached
```

When I issue  command it gives me below error.

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,
       {{shutdown,
            {failed_to_start_child,'rabbit_stomp_listener_sup_:::61613',
                {shutdown,
                    {failed_to_start_child,tcp_listener,
                        {cannot_listen,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613,eaddrinuse}}}}},
        {rabbit_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   C:/Users/IISU45/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/hare .log
   C:/Users/IISU45/AppData/Roaming/RabbitMQ/log/hare -sasl.log

{"init terminating in do_boot",{could_not_start,rabbitmq_stomp,{{shutdown,{faile
d_to_start_child,'rabbit_stomp_listener_sup_:::61613',{shutdown,{failed_to_start
_child,tcp_listener,{cannot_listen,{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},61613,eaddrinuse}}}}},{rabb
it_stomp,start,[normal,[]]}}}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I have also visited the above link : [Stuck with "A cluster on a single machine" explained in https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738152/stuck-with-a-cluster-on-a-single-machine-explained-in-https-www-rabbitmq-com)

But still I'm facing same issue.

RabbitMQ version : rabbitmq-server-3.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html plugin enabled.

The port `61613` is in use.

Change also the stomp port:

```
[
  {rabbitmq_stomp, [{tcp_listeners, [{"127.0.0.1", 61614},
                                     {"::1",       61614}]}]}
].
```

Answer (score 0):

i face the same question. my solution is that: close rabbit conflict plugin.

1. use rabbitmq-plugins list show enable plugins.
2. Base `rabbitmq-plugins list` results, disable conflict port plugin. for example, your conflict port is 61613,  conflict plugin is rabbit_stomp. Disable the conflict plugin as far as you can create two rabbitmq nodes.